# Getting wrong Base64 encoded result in GO

Tags: go, base64

I have the following hex data created by converting 5 values(consists of name, numeric and date field) to TLV

```
0115426f627320426173656d656e74205265636f726473020f3130303032353930363730303030330314323032322d30342d32355431353a33303a30305a040a323130303130302e393905093331353031352e3135
```

This hex data needs to be further encoded to Base64. I wrote the below code for that

```
func TLVsToBase64(v string) string { // v - the TLV in hex format
    
    encodedTLV := b64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(v))
    return encodedTLV

}
```

The output(which is wrong) of the aforementioned hex data is below:

```
MDExNTQyNmY2MjczMjA0MjYxNzM2NTZkNjU2ZTc0MjA1MjY1NjM2ZjcyNjQ3MzAyMGYzMTMwMzAzMDMyMzUzOTMwMzYzNzMwMzAzMDMwMzMwMzE0MzIzMDMyMzIyZDMwMzQyZDMyMzU1NDMxMzUzYTMzMzAzYTMwMzA1YTA0MGEzMjMxMzAzMDMxMzAzMDJlMzkzOTA1MDkzMzMxMzUzMDMxMzUyZTMxMzU=
```

The desired output is:

```
ARVCb2JzIEJhc2VtZW50IFJlY29yZHMCDzEwMDAyNTkwNjcwMDAwMwMUMjAyMi0wNC0yNVQxNTozMDowMFoECjIxMDAxMDAuOTkFCTMxNTAxNS4xNQ==
```

I am new to Go, so please help me to troubleshoot the issue. I might missed something

Comment: Do you realize that the main point of the linked Q/A is exactly the same as in the answer below, even written by the same person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input is the hexadecimal representation of some data. And your expected output is not the Base64 encoding of the UTF-8 data of the hex representation, but rather the data (the bytes) the hex encoding represent, so first decode the bytes e.g. using [`hex.DecodeString()`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/hex#DecodeString):

```
func TLVsToBase64(v string) (string, error) { // v - the TLV in hex format
    data, err := hex.DecodeString(v)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    encodedTLV := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(data)
    return encodedTLV, nil
}
```

Testing it:

```
s := "0115426f627320426173656d656e74205265636f726473020f3130303032353930363730303030330314323032322d30342d32355431353a33303a30305a040a323130303130302e393905093331353031352e3135"
fmt.Println(TLVsToBase64(s))
```

Output is what you expect (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/d2VjomwtvAu)):

```
ARVCb2JzIEJhc2VtZW50IFJlY29yZHMCDzEwMDAyNTkwNjcwMDAwMwMUMjAyMi0wNC0yNVQxNTozMDowMFoECjIxMDAxMDAuOTkFCTMxNTAxNS4xNQ== <nil>
```